# User Settings binding on fields is clearing fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, application-settings

I created a UserControl containing 4 text boxes, and 4 properties pointing on the text properties of each textbox :

```
    public virtual string Server
    {
        get { return txtDBServer.Text; }
        set { txtDBServer.Text = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Database
    {
        get { return txtDBName.Text; }
        set { txtDBName.Text = value; }
    }

    public virtual string User
    {
        get { return txtDBUser.Text; }
        set { txtDBUser.Text = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Pass
    {
        get { return txtDBPass.Text; }
        set { txtDBPass.Text = value; }
    }
```

Then I used this control on a Windows Form and bind these 4 properties to a user setting. This is the VS generated code :

```
        this.sqlCx.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Server", global::Devtools.WinApp.User.Default, "Server", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        this.sqlCx.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Database", global::Devtools.WinApp.User.Default, "Database", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        this.sqlCx.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("User", global::Devtools.WinApp.User.Default, "UserName", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        this.sqlCx.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Pass", global::Devtools.WinApp.User.Default, "Pass", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

When I execute the application, only the first field "Server" is maintained between executions, but the 3 other fields are reset to empty when the user control loses focus.

Why is that happening and how to prevent it ?

Comment: DataBindings don't act like a list. You're adding to the `sqlCx` instead of `button1`, `button2`, etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes, I'm adding to 4 properties of my user control, don't understand how this is different than 4 properties of a textbox, it should be hidden from the outside of the user control that these properties set and gets a nested textbox!